# Is it possible to have a file "represent" the contents of a folder?

Tags: linux, macos

I usually need to store different files that are logically related to each other for different projects (`example pairs: data-metadata, script-configuration, run_input-run_result-run_log`).

Most of these cases, I use one file 90% of the time, and rarely I need to change a configuration, see the logs for debugging etc. Therefore seeing these secondary/complementary files around all the time bothers me a little (it feels my organization is bit messy).

I'm not sure if there is a convention for this but I'd like to create my own logical units that are represented by single file in the simplest possible way (eg something similar to application bundles but without generating extra files, or needing xcode or build for it).

Say in an example, I have runs of three files I'd like to group: `run1_input.json - run1_result.json - run1_log.txt`. For each "run" I create a file-like folder, say `run1.json`. I would like to be able to do `cd run1.json`, `open run1.json`, `ls run1.json`, `open run1.json/run1_input.json`, as I would if `run1.json` was just a regular directory. But specifically when I double click on `run1.json` I would like to have `run1_result.json` to be opened as if I clicked `run1.json/run1_result.json`.

So basically I'm looking for a way to have a file in a directory "represent" its parent directory. Is that possible?

Bonus: I'd also be interested the same in Linux, although I'm immediately planning to use it in MacOS at the moment

Comment: Are you looking for symlinks?

Comment: Why not use sub-folders?

Comment: @harrymc because I do this often and its kind of a recurring theme in many projects. So ideally I just want to setup a default file when I try to click on a folder as a way of organizing my work

Comment: @EugenRieck Not exactly but that would be some solution. I could have a symlink to `run1/run1_result.json` for example, but then I need to keep `run1` folder itself somewhere. idealy I have a single entity that represents a logical unit (I'm simply looking for this to be better organized and have more convenient behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *Finder* to behave in this way, then I do think you need to use Bundles (or write your own Finder extension).  Bundles shouldn't be that hard to use.  I don't think you need XCode to create them.

It sounds like you're a programmer, so create an "app" through the tool Platypus, just have it run any simple shell script. You can then use the app the Platypus creates as a template for your folders/apps.  Go into the folder/app/bundle and just edit the script that the app runs so it runs a "textedit run1_result.json" kind of command.  Double-clicking the app/bundle will open your output file.  You can do all the complex stuff with symlinks (and maybe editing which file the script opens) in the script, or make it behave to the *name* of the folder/app to know which output file to open.

You might want to write another script that takes your template app/bundle/script and structures it for each of these things you want to bundle.  After that, your code runs normally in the Terminal but you can interact with the output by double-clicking the Finder app/bundle.

Since it sounds like you also have input that you might want to edit (thru the Finder too), maybe you want to define and use an environment variable (that you could set manually, thru Automator, etc.) when you want to toggle between input and output modes.  Toggle the mode, double-click on the app/bundle, and the shell script will open the input or output file, based on the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’ll give that a try!